# Passing certs to curl from an environment variable

Tags: bash, curl, hashicorp-vault

I am working on a CORS monitor for my application, and need to do the following:

1. Download certificates from our Hashicorp Vault instance
2. Curl an endpoint using those certs
3. Evaluate the response

I can do this currently as follows:

```
vault kv get -field crt my/cert/path/CACERT > CACERT.crt
vault kv get -field crt my/cert/path/TESTCERT > CERT.crt
vault kv get -field key my/cert/path/TESTCERT > KEY.key

curl -v\
    --cacert CACERAT.crt \
    --cert CERT.crt \
    --key KEY.key \
    --location \
    --request GET 'https://my.end.point'
# <evaluate here>
rm CACERT.crt CERT.crt KEY.key
```

While this works, I would prefer to not write the certs to a file, and would rather keep them in memory, such as using environment variables or maybe some bash-isms I'm not aware of.

In my mind it would look something more like this:

```
CACERT=$(vault kv get -field crt my/cert/path/CACERT)
CERT=$(vault kv get -field crt my/cert/path/TESTCERT)
KEY=$(vault kv get -field key my/cert/path/TESTCERT)

curl -v\
    --cacert $CACERT \
    --cert $CERT \
    --key $KEY \
    --location \
    --request GET 'https://my.end.point'
# <evaluate here>
```

Obviously this wont work, as curl is expecting file paths, but for illustrative purposes, is this possible? If possible, is it a poor approach? Perhaps there is another way to approach this that I haven't considered? I am aware that I could do the above with python relatively easily, however I'd prefer to stick to bash + curl if at all possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bash supports [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html) using the `<(cmd)` syntax. This causes the output of `cmd` to be substituted with a filename. This allows you to pass command output as an argument where a filename is expected.

In your example, you would do something like this:

```
CACERT=$(vault kv get -field crt my/cert/path/CACERT)
CERT=$(vault kv get -field crt my/cert/path/TESTCERT)
KEY=$(vault kv get -field key my/cert/path/TESTCERT)

curl -v \
    --cacert <(echo "$CACERT") \
    --cert <(echo "$CERT") \
    --key <(echo "$KEY") \
    --location \
    --request GET 'https://my.end.point'
```

Comment: You are redirecting echo output to the stdin of curl and each successive redirection is erasing the preceding one. It will not work at all. And `<(echo "$variable")` can be replaced by a here-string `<<<"$variable"`. Anyway I am sorry your answer is broken.

Comment: @LéaGris - The `<(cmd)` syntax performs process substitution, not redirection. Bash replaces the whole construct with a valid, fully-qualified filename. That "file" acts like a named pipe (and, depending on the platform, actually is one). When read, this "file" will return the output of `cmd`. As an example, `grep one <(printf 'one\ntwo\n')` will print `one`. The link provided fully describes the feature.

Comment: Thank you, I was wrong and mixed the `<(cmd)` syntax with the expansion of it as a redirection `< <(cmd)`. My bad!

Answer (score 0):

With a POSIX only shell, it is possible to replace process substitution with explicitly created named pipes.

Background tasks streams the different keys and certificates to their dedicated named pipe.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

# These are the randomly named pipes
cacert_pipe=$(mktemp -u)
cert_pipe=$(mktemp -u)
key_pipe=$(mktemp -u)

# Remove the named pipes on exit
trap 'rm -f -- "$cacert_pipe" "$cert_pipe" "$key_pipe"' EXIT

# Create the named pipes
mkfifo -- "$cacert_pipe" "$cert_pipe" "$key_pipe" || exit 1

# Start background shells to stream data to the respective named pipes
vault kv get -field crt my/cert/path/CACERT >"$cacert_pipe" &
vault kv get -field crt my/cert/path/TESTCERT >"$cert_pipe" &
vault kv get -field key my/cert/path/TESTCERT >"$key_pipe" &

curl -v\
    --cacert "$cacert_pipe" \
    --cert "$cert_pipe" \
    --key "$key_pipe" \
    --location \
    --request GET 'https://example.com/my.end.point'
```

The downside compared the Bash's process substitution method is; the streaming tasks need to be restarted explicitly before calling `curl` with the named pipes as files arguments.